# Ladder diagrams using Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

[image: a ladder diagram]

This is a ladder diagram I need help in drawing it using Tikz, please help me.

Comment: People appreciate if you indicate what you have tried. Did you read the manual for the tikz-cd package, for example?

Comment: The manual you mentioned have just the basic and simple examples

Comment: An given a little thought those examples should be enough to produce something that looks like this. At the moment this question is more like: please make this for me, a type of question generally disliked here. At least show a bit of effort

Comment: @daleif. No, you are wrong it's not like this.

Answer (score 14):

You can use a `\foreach` loop like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,quotes}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node(g-0){$G_{i_0}$};
  \node(h-0)[below right=1cm of g-0]{$h_{j_0}$};
  \foreach \i [count=\j from 0]in {1,...,3}{
  \ifnum\i<3{
    \node [right=2cm of g-\j](g-\i){$G_{i_\i}$}; 
    \node [right=2cm of h-\j](h-\i){$H_{j_\i}$};
  }\else{
    \node [right=2cm of g-\j](g-\i){$G_{i_\i} \dots$}; 
    \node [right=2cm of h-\j](h-\i){$\dots$};
  }\fi
  \path (g-\j) edge[<-,"$\lambda_{i_\j i_\i}$"] (g-\i) edge[<-] (h-\j);
  \path (h-\j) edge[<-] (g-\i) edge[<-,"$\mu_{j_\j j_\i}$"] (h-\i);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Here's an implementation with `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=small]
G_{i_0} &&
  G_{i_1} \arrow[ll,swap,"\lambda_{i_0,i_1}"] \arrow[dl] &&
  G_{i_2} \arrow[ll,swap,"\lambda_{i_1,i_2}"] \arrow[dl] &&
  G_{i_3}\makebox[0pt][l]{ $\cdots$}
    \arrow[ll,swap,"\lambda_{i_2,i_3}"] \arrow[dl] &&
\\
& H_{j_0} \arrow[ul] &&
  H_{j_1} \arrow[ll,swap,"\mu_{j_0,j_1}"] \arrow[ul] &&
  H_{j_2} \arrow[ll,swap,"\mu_{j_1,j_2}"] \arrow[ul] &&
  \cdots \arrow[ll,swap,"\mu_{j_2,j_3}"]
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The package [`xymatrix`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xymatrix) is also good at this sort of diagram.

[image: A ladder-style diagram]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[arrow,matrix,pdf]{xy}
\begin{document}
\begin{xymatrix}@C20pt{
    G_{i_0}\ar@{<-}[rr]^{\lambda_{{i_0},{i_1}}}\ar@{<-}[rd] &&
    G_{i_1}\ar@{<-}[rr]^{\lambda_{{i_1},{i_2}}}\ar@{<-}[rd] && 
    G_{i_2}\ar@{<-}[rr]^{\lambda_{{i_2},{i_3}}}\ar@{<-}[rd] && 
    G_{i_3}\rlap{$\cdots$}\ar@{<-}[rd] \\
  & H_{j_0}\ar@{<-}[rr]^{\mu_{{j_0},{j_1}}}\ar@{<-}[ru] &&
    H_{j_1}\ar@{<-}[rr]^{\mu_{{j_1},{j_2}}}\ar@{<-}[ru] && 
    H_{j_2}\ar@{<-}[rr]^{\mu_{{j_2},{j_3}}}\ar@{<-}[ru] &&
    H_{j_3}\rlap{$\cdots$} \\
} 
\end{xymatrix}
\end{document}
```

### Notes

- Options to the `xy` package: `arrow` defines the `\ar...` command; `matrix` defines the `xymatrix` environment; and `pdf` makes the output look better.
- The syntax of the `xymatrix` environment is `[setup]{rows...}`.  Here the `setup` is `@C20pt` which sets the cell spacing to `20pt`.
- The rows are like a regular tabular - `&` to delimit cells `\\` to mark lines.
- Each cell consists of some maths mode text, followed by one or more arrows.
- The `\ar` syntax is: `\ar @{style} [direction] ^{upper label}`.
- Labels and styles are optional.
- Style `@{<-}` draws a reverse arrow.
- Direction `[rr]` extends the arrow two cells to the right, `[ru]` one right, one up, and so on...
- I used `\rlap` for the dots at the end, in order to get the spacing right.

Answer (score 1):

And how about a `luamplib` version, showing off some Unicode maths?

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[math-style=upright]{Neo Euler}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
vardef connect(expr a, b) = 
  drawarrow a--b cutbefore fullcircle scaled 22 shifted a
                 cutafter  fullcircle scaled 22 shifted b
enddef;                
beginfig(1);
c = r = 42;

string upper_node_name, upper_arrow_mark, 
       lower_node_name, lower_arrow_mark; 

pair A,B,C,D;       

ahangle := 25; % slim arrow heads

for i=0 upto 2:

  upper_node_name := "$G_{i_" & decimal i & "}$";
  lower_node_name := "$H_{i_" & decimal i & "}$";
  upper_arrow_mark := "$λ_{i_" & decimal i & ",i_" & decimal (i+1) & "}$";
  lower_arrow_mark := "$μ_{i_" & decimal i & ",i_" & decimal (i+1) & "}$";

  A := (2c*i,0);         B := A shifted (2c,0);
  C := A shifted (c,-r); D := C shifted (2c,0);

  label(upper_node_name, A);
  label(lower_node_name, C);
  label.top(upper_arrow_mark, 1/2[A,B]);
  label.top(lower_arrow_mark, 1/2[C,D]);

  connect(B,A);
  connect(C,A);
  connect(B,C);
  connect(D,C);

endfor

label("$G_{i_3}$\rlap{$\cdots$}", B);
label("$\cdots$", D);

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's an elegant way of getting some space around the expressions. I typically draw the labels as a pic and then do `cutbefore bbox label1` etc.

Comment: @Aditya - thank you - I think a rounded "invisible" boundary often looks nicer but I have hard coded the `22` here.  You could use something like `fullcircle scaled abs(urcorner label1-llcorner label1)` to get a more automatic size.  A `superellipse` shape can also look nice.